# How to add JS and CSS to all content parts in an Orchard module

Tags: css, orchardcms

I am writing a module for Orchard CMS 1.8.1

I would like to add custom styles to all content parts that I have written for the module. I need these to work regardless of the theme chosen by the website admins. I could add links to the CSS and JS files in every view file for every content part - but that seems messy and prone to future bugs - what's the best way to have a single file that loads up the styles needed for all my content parts?

Should I provide a different Content.cshtml that includes the links? This also seems like it could be problematic if the admins need their own control over the main Content.cshtml

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handler should do the trick, I wrote this from the top of my head so not sure if it really works.

First create `ResourceManifest.cs` and define your stylesheets and scripts

```
public class ResourceManifest : IResourceManifestProvider
{
    public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
    {
        var manifest = builder.Add();
        manifest.DefineStyle("MyStylesheet").SetUrl("mystylesheet.min.css", "mystylesheet.css").SetVersion("1.0.0");
        manifest.DefineScript("MyScript").SetUrl("myscript.min.js", "myscript.js").SetVersion("1.0.0");
    }
}
```

Then it should be enough to create content handler and override the `BuildDisplayShape`

```
public class MyResourceHandler : ContentHandler
{
    private readonly Work<IResourceManager> _resourceManager;

    public MyResourceHandler(Work<IResourceManager> resourceManager)
    {
        _resourceManager = resourceManager;
    }

    protected override void BuildDisplayShape(BuildDisplayContext context)
    {
        if (context.DisplayType == "Detail" && context.ContentItem.Has(typeof(MyPart)))
        {
            this._resourceManager.Value.Require("stylesheet", "MyStylesheet");
            this._resourceManager.Value.Require("script", "MyScript");
        }

        base.BuildDisplayShape(context);
    }
}
```

Adjust the IF as necessary. And let me know if it works ;)

*Beauty of using ResourceManifest with versioning is that anyone can replace your stylesheets/javascript with their own just by defining style in their own ResourceManifest (module/theme) with same name and higher version number and don't have to touch any original files.*

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a go on Monday and report back!